# multiple using for editorforModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

editorforModel but Now I need several different ones and I dont want to use html helpers onebyone. So I need something like this ;

```
  @model JobTrackingSystem.Areas.Panel.ViewModels.Member.NewMemberModel
  {

     @Html.EditorForModel()

  }

  @model JobTrackingSystem.Areas.Panel.ViewModels.Member.MemberDashboardModel
  {
     @Html.EditorForModel()
  }
```

So I want to keep them in 2 different divs in 1 page but also my controller wont allow using something like this 
here is my controller ;

```
 public ActionResult Add(NewMemberModel input, HttpPostedFileBase Resim)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("Hatalı İşlem Yaptınız.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if (Resim == null)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("Lütfen Boş Alan Bırakmayın.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var epostaKontrol = Db.MyMembers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Mail == input.Mail);
        if (epostaKontrol != null)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("E-Mail Adresi Adı Kullanımda.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        string[] folders = new string[] { "Uploads/Member/Orjinal/", "Uploads/Member/Kucuk/" };

        string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(Path.GetFileName(Resim.FileName)).ToLower();
        string orjName = Guid.NewGuid() + fileExt;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/" + folders[0]), orjName);
        string fileThumbPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/" + folders[1]), orjName);
        if (!(fileExt.Equals(".jpg") || fileExt.Equals(".jpeg") || fileExt.Equals(".png")))
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("Yalnızca .Jpg .Jpeg ve .Png Uzantılı Dosyalar Yükleyebilirsiniz.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        Resim.SaveAs(filePath);

        var thumber = ImageHelper.Thumber(750, filePath, fileThumbPath);
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thumber))
        {
            ShowErrorMessage(thumber);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var item = new Member
        {
            Name = input.Name,
            Mail = input.Mail,
            SurName = input.SurName,
            Phone = input.Phone,
            Sira = Db.MyMembers.Max(m => (short?)m.Sira) ?? 0 + 1,
            DepartmentType = (DepartmentTypeForUser)input.DepartmentTypeFor,
            MemberType = (MemberTypeForUser)input.MemberTypeFor,
            Image = "/" + folders[1] + orjName
        };
        item.SetPassword(input.Password);
        Db.MyMembers.Add(item);
        Db.SaveChanges();

        ImageResizeModel model = new ImageResizeModel()
        {
            ImagePath = "/" + folders[1] + orjName,
            ImageThumbPath = "/" + folders[1] + orjName,
            SelectionSize = "[ 750, 750 ]",
        };
        return View("CropImage", model);

    }
```

So How can I use multiple `editorforModel` for multiple times with different model field ? can I do anything in `NewMemberModel` class something like 2 methods and then call `editorforModelMethod1 - editorforModelMethod2` ?

Comment: You can only have one model per view, so it's not possible to have multiple EditorForMode's with different models in a single view.  You can, however, create a composite view model that includes both.

Comment: Well Yea but when I create all I need in one model and use editorformodel then it brings all model for per page but I need to use it in 4 different pages with form wizard so ı kinda need to use a few editorformodel or just regular way for html helper

Comment: CodeCaster fixed my issue ı think I havent explained properly that What I need. Thank you for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking (especially "controller won't allow", an actual error message would help us and could help you research the issue), but it looks like you could use a composite viewmodel:

```
public class NewMemberWithDashboardModel
{
    public NewMemberModel NewMember { get; set; }

    public MemberDashboardModel MemberDashboard { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewMember)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MemberDashboard)
```

And in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Add(NewMemberWithDashboardModel model, ...)
```

Comment: well actually I think I can do it with ur answer and I'm gonna try it as soon as possible. and will tell you if its okay

Comment: Thank you very much mate it worked well. You are the savior. ı dont know why I couldnt think of it :D  @CodeCaster